# Share an object with another Vue component

Tags: vue.js

I know this has been asked several times before, but as a Vue.js beginner I had trouble interpreting some of the other discussions and applying them to my situation. Using this [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0o86rww1v), how would one pass the indicated object from "Hello" to "Goodbye" when the corresponding button is pressed? I'm unsure if I should be trying to use props, a global event bus, a plugin, vuex, or simply some sort of global variable.

Edit:
Here is the code for App.vue, Hello.vue and Goodbye.vue (from the previously linked CodeSandbox example).

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app"
};
</script>
```

Hello.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
      <h1>This is Hello</h1>
    <div v-for="(obj, index) in objects" :key="index">
        <router-link class="button" :to="{ path: '/goodbye'}">Share obj[{{ index }}] with Goodbye</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "hello",
  data() {
    return {
      objects: [0, 1, 2, 3]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Goodbye.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="goodbye">
      <h1>This is Goodbye</h1>
    <p>Obj = "???"</p>
    <router-link class="button" :to="{ path: '/hello'}">Hello</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "goodbye"
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are used to share data with child components. Since the components never exist at the same time, this is not useful for you. Similarly, events are not very useful to you here. You can send an event on a global bus, but since the other component does not exist yet, it cannot listen for the event.

I am not sure what you would want to do with a plugin in this case. You should never use a global variable, unless you have a very good reason to (e.g. you use Google Analytics, which happens to use a global variable, or you want to expose something within Vue in development mode for debugging purposes). In your case, you likely want to change some global app state, which is exactly what Vuex was made for. Call a Vuex mutator or action either when clicking, or in a router hook such as [`router.beforeEach`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-beforeeach) to save the information in a structured manner so you can then retrieve it with a mapped getter. Keep in mind that you want to structure your vuex store, so don't use a state variable `thingsIWantToShareWithGoodbye`, but instead split it up in `previousPage`, `lastClickOffset` and `numberOfClicks`.

For example:

```
// store/index.js
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  button: null
};

const getters = {
  button(state) {
    return state.button;
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setButton(state, payload) {
    state.button = payload;
  }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
});
```

```
// Hello.vue
<template>
  <div class="hello">
      <h1>This is Hello</h1>
    <div v-for="(obj, index) in objects" :key="index">
        <router-link @click.native="setButtonState(obj)" class="button" :to="{ path: '/goodbye'}">Share obj[{{ index }}] with Goodbye</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "hello",
  data() {
    return {
      objects: [0, 1, 2, 3]
    };
  },

  methods: {
    setButtonState (obj) {
      this.$store.commit('setButton', obj)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
// Goodbye.vue
<template>
    <div class="goodbye">
      <h1>This is Goodbye</h1>
    <p>Obj = {{ button }}</p>
    <router-link class="button" :to="{ path: '/hello'}">Hello</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: "goodbye",

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      button: 'button'
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

[image: Edit Vue Routing Example]

Comment: Thanks for also explaining why the other approaches were not applicable